# Univalent functions whitch are not starlike or convex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

$S$ denotes the univalent function class, $S=\{f \in \mathcal{A}:f \in H_{u}(\mathrm{U})\}$.
$S^{\ast}=\left\{f\in\mathcal{A}:\operatorname{Re}\frac{zf^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)}>0,
\;z\in\mathrm{U}\right\}$ is the starlike functions class and $K=\left\{f\in\mathcal{A}:\operatorname{Re}\frac{zf^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^{\prime}(z)}+1>0,\;z\in\mathrm{U}\right\}$ is the convex functions class. We know that $K \subset S^{\ast} \subset S$,and i need 2 examples for an univalent function ($S$), but not starlike ($S^{\ast}$), and a function whitch is univalent ($S$) and not convex ($K$), with proof if it's possible. (I know that the Koebe function is starlike but not convex)

Comment: It would be better to include the definitions of univalent and starlike functions, because, in my opinion, these terms are not common and/or known across all fields of mathematics.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: You need some non-convex / non-starlike (wrt $0$) domains such that you know how to construct a conformal map from the unit disk to them.  Do you know how to univalently map unit disk to halfplane? And then to an angle $>\pi $?  That's not convex. And if you move $0$ to a certain point, it won't be starlike with respect to $0$, either.

Comment: I just need to prove that $S \not\subset K$ and $S\not\subset S^{\ast} $, so i need 2 function (or 1) to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

user147263 Jun 4 '14 at 22:21  gave an answer.

Let D be domain in w-plane defined by   -\pi/4< arg w <5 \pi/4  and  let
G=D +(-1)  and f conformal mapping  of the unit disk onto  G such that f(0)=0.

Since  G is  non-convex / non-starlike (wrt 0) domain,  f is not  starlike.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=z\{(1 - z)^{-2 e^{it} Co(t)}\}$ with $|t|< \pi/2$.

This function is univalent but not starlike. Implying S contains S* properly. 
For the case, S is not in K, the well known Koebe function will work.